# Django REST Framework user registration Validation confusion

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to register a user with Django REST API with `two different methods`

With `method 1` everything works fine but it gives

This problem :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952178/django-rest-framework-user-registration-confusion

And with `method 2` it gives the following error **but is creating users in backend**

> AttributeError at /api/users/register/
>
> Got AttributeError when
>   attempting to get a value for field `password2` on serializer
>   `UserCreateSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute
>   'password2'.

***Code:***

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

from rest_framework.serializers import (ModelSerializer,CharField)

User = get_user_model()


class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    password2 = CharField(label='Confirm Password')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',
            'password2',
            'email',
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password' : {'write_only': True},
            'password2': {'write_only': True},
        }

    def validate_password(self, value):
        data = self.get_initial()
        password = data.get('password2')
        password2 = value
        if password != password2:
            raise ValidationError('Passwords must match')
        return value

    def validate_password2(self, value):
        data = self.get_initial()
        password = data.get('password')
        password2 = value
        if password != password2:
            raise ValidationError('Passwords must match')
        return value
```

**method 1:**

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    username = validated_data['username']
    email = validated_data['email']
    password = validated_data['password']
    user_obj = User(
        username=username,
        email=email
    )
    user_obj.set_password(password)
    user_obj.save()
    return validated_data
```

**method 2:**

```
 def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            username=validated_data['username'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

> Note: Using Python3 , Django 10.7 & Django REST framework 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django REST Framework user registration confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952178/django-rest-framework-user-registration-confusion)

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your method is that you are passing the password2, which is not an attribute of the User model.

From reading your code, I think you could try something like this,

Instead of repeatedly validating each password field you could do an object wide validation for that.

```
def validate(self, data):
    password = data.get('password')
    confirm_password = data.pop('password2')
    if password != confirm_password:
        raise ValidationError('.............')
    return data
```

The create method you have written would suffice, I hope..
Try this and let me know if anything comes up..

**EDIT**

Edit your create method,

```
def create (self, validated_data):
    email = validated_data.get('email')
    username = validated_data.get('username')
    password = validated_data.get('password')
    try:
        user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

The KeyError maybe triggered, if any of the email, password, username are not available.

Comment: Tried your code but it gives `KeyError`. Could you please suggest or guide how to add `password2` as attribute of `User` model.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Password2 is not a field in User model, therefore when serializing, password2 must be removed after validation or before reaching create method. Else django raises attribute error.

Comment: Also in the create method try using User.objects.create(username=username, email=email), then set password.

Comment: This worked for me.. thanks @zaidfazil.. however I think create_user works better because it does the password hashing for you

Answer (score 0):

please try this: add `write_only=True` in the `password2`

```
class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    password2 = CharField(label='Confirm Password', write_only=True)
    ...
```